# Animating the trajectory change using core animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, caanimation

I have basic UILabel that animates along a full circle using CACAKeyframeAnimation:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(path,nil, center.x,center.y, radius , DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(from_degree), DEGREES_TO_RADIANS((360+from_degree)), NO);

CAKeyframeAnimation *theAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];

theAnimation.path = path;
CGPathRelease(path);

// set the animation properties
theAnimation.duration = duration;
theAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
theAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
theAnimation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
theAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;

[label.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"position"];
```

Is there a way to animate the radius change of the arc and propagate that change to labels that moving along the path?

Answer (score -1):

```
 CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath, NULL, 100.f, 100.f);
 CGPathAddLineToPoint(thePath, NULL, 200.f, 100.f);
 CGPathAddArc(thePath, NULL, 100.f, 100.f, 100.f, 0.f, (360* M_PI)/180, NO);
 CGPathCloseSubpath(thePath);
```

U can Use This :)

Comment: Can you explain how this answers my question? I can already change the path. I want the transition between the paths.

Answer (score -2):

```
 CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, 100.f, 100.f, 100.f, 0.f, (360* M_PI)/180, NO);


    CAKeyframeAnimation *theAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];

    theAnimation.path = path;
    CGPathRelease(path);

    // set the animation properties
    theAnimation.duration = 3.0;
    theAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    theAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
    theAnimation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
    theAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;

    [self.lblTest.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"position"];
```

Try This.. It will Helps You :)

Comment: This is the exact code I put in my question, I'm asking how to animate the change of path. If I kill this function second time with a different circle I want a transiation

Comment: This is what I'm already using , you simply don't get the question.